# Extract and Use System Output (Batch)

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write a batch file that allows for quicker assembling of multiple assembly files using the A86 assembler and to view the result.  There are two cases, when there is an assembly error and when there is no error.

Sample Assembler Input:

```
A86 FILE1.ASM FILE2.ASM FILE3.ASM FILE4.ASM
```

Case 1: error.  Supposing there was an error in FILE3.ASM, the system will output on line 4:

```
Error messages inserted into FILE3.ASM
```

Case 2: no error. The system will output on line 4:

```
Object: FILE1.BIN
```

In case 1, I would like to open the file that generated an error using Notepad++, using the command `notepad++ FILENAME.ASM`.

In case 2, I would like to open the generated object in a hex editor using the command `HxD FILENAME.BIN`.

What can be done to extract the error/success file name from the system output?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with `A86`, but I have an idea or two.  If `A86` returns zero on success, non-zero on fail, then I would do it this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if defined PROGRAMFILES(X86) (set "pf=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%") else set "pf=%PROGRAMFILES%"

:: path to notepad++
set "npp=%pf%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

:: path to hxd (fix this, please)
set "hxd=%pf%\HXD\hxd.exe"

set idx=1

for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%A in (
    'A86 FILE1.ASM FILE2.ASM FILE3.ASM FILE4.ASM 2^>^&1'
) do (
    if !idx! equ 4 (
        rem if %errorlevel% is non-zero (is 1 or higher)
        if ERRRORLEVEL 1 (
            start "" "%npp%" %%E
        ) else (
            start "" "%hxd%" %%B
        )
    )
    echo(%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F
    set /a "idx+=1"
)
```

If the errorlevel returned by `A86` is not a reliable indicator, then change `if ERRORLEVEL 1` to `if "%%J"==""`

You didn't mention whether error output of `A86` is sent via stderr or stdout, so I redirected stderr to stdout in the `for` loop with `2^>^&1`.  I have no clue whether it's needed or not, but it shouldn't hurt anything if not.